# Bash Switch directory and creating ZIP

Tags: bash

To describe the below script, I'm trying to create zip file based on the startdir path which contains data folder (/root/Archive/EKS/data) (root/Elasticsearch/data) when i'm running the below  script

1. first entering into the **/root/Archive/EKS/data** path and its making zip from same directory its self without entering data folder.
2. But if you see next iteration entering into  **/root/Elasticsearch/data** path and its making zip from inside the data directory and making zip file based on the list of directory.

```
#!/bin/bash

startdir=(
"/root/Archive/EKS/data"
"/root/Elasticsearch/data"
)

   for sub_dir in "${startdir[@]}"/*/ ; do
     echo "$sub_dir"
     zip "${sub_dir%/}".zip "$sub_dir"
     echo "clean"
done
```

bash -x script

```
/root/Archive/EKS/data
  adding: root/Archive/EKS/data/ (stored 0%)

/root/Elasticsearch/data/abc-cleanup-es-index/
  adding: root/Elasticsearch/data/abc-cleanup-es-index/ (stored 0%)

/root/Elasticsearch/data/abc-export-cw-logs/
  adding: root/Elasticsearch/data/abc-export-cw-logs/ (stored 0%)

/root/Elasticsearch/data/abc-log-to-es/
  adding: root/Elasticsearch/data/abc-log-to-es/ (stored 0%)
```

```
1st Iteration this is wrong output
└─# pwd
/root/Archive/EKS

┌──(root㉿user)-[~/Archive/EKS]
└─# ls -lrt
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4096 May 20 12:18 data
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  198 May 20 13:26 data.zip


2nd Iteration this is correct output
┌──(root㉿user)-[~/Elasticsearch/data]
└─# ls -lrt

drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 May 17 14:43 abc-dir1
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 May 17 14:43 abc-dir2
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 May 17 14:43 abc-dir3
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  230 May 20 13:26 abc-dir1.zip
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  240 May 20 13:26 abc-dir2.zip
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  244 May 20 13:26 abc-dir3.zip
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When bash expands `"${startdir[@]}"`, it's going to put each entry as a separate quoted 'word':

```
"/root/Archive/EKS/data" "/root/Elasticsearch/data"
```

Then on the end of that, it will add `/*/`, giving:

```
"/root/Archive/EKS/data" "/root/Elasticsearch/data"/*/
```

The first word is just a literal string, but the second has a wildcard which will be expanded based on the filesystem:

```
"/root/Archive/EKS/data" "/root/Elasticsearch/data/abc-whatever" "/root/Elasticsearch/data/def-blah"
```

If there were more entries in the list, only the last one would have `/*/` added to the end, so only that one would be expanded to sub-directories.

What you actually want is to first loop over each directory, and then apply the wildcard:

```
for dir in "${startdir[@]}" ; do
    for sub_dir in "$dir"/*/ ; do
        echo "$sub_dir"
        zip "${sub_dir%/}".zip "$sub_dir"
        echo "clean"
    done
done
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your loveable time, its working as we expected.. You saved for last 3 days work.